# How to convert unequal list to nested dictionary using zip?

Tags: python

How can I convert this list to nested dictionary?

```
studentName = ["kelly","Micheal","Agatha","Chris","frank","matthew"]
subject  = ["math","phy","chem"]
math = [34,45,78,79,60,36]
phy = [57,98,67,90,56,60]
chem = [67,86,35,98,50,67]
```

To get this output:

```
{
    kelly:{math:34,phy:57,chem:67},
    micheal:{math:45,phy:98,chem:86},
    Agatha:{math:78,phy:67,chem:35},
    chris:{math:79,phy:90,chem:98},
    frank:{math:60,phy:56,chem:50},
    matthew: {math:36,phy:60,chem:67},
}
```

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i tried using zip but i noticed that i can only apply zip to equal list

Comment: How do you apply "zip" to lists of different lengths (code), what happens, what should happen (edit the question)?

Comment: You can do it easily by only applying zip to the four equal lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest `zip`s:

```py
studentName = ["kelly","Micheal","Agatha","Chris","frank","matthew"]
subject  = ["math","phy","chem"]
math = [34,45,78,79,60,36]
phy = [57,98,67,90,56,60]
chem = [67,86,35,98,50,67]

output = {name: dict(zip(subject, scores)) for name, scores in
                                                zip(studentName, zip(math, phy, chem))}
print(output)
# {'kelly': {'math': 34, 'phy': 57, 'chem': 67},
#  'Micheal': {'math': 45, 'phy': 98, 'chem': 86},
#  'Agatha': {'math': 78, 'phy': 67, 'chem': 35},
#  'Chris': {'math': 79, 'phy': 90, 'chem': 98},
#  'frank': {'math': 60, 'phy': 56, 'chem': 50},
#  'matthew': {'math': 36, 'phy': 60, 'chem': 67}}
```